# Navigation within a phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova, window.location

I am playing around with the local storage on PhoneGap, trying to create a JavaScript login. My current problem is when I run the application, it will not go to the main menu if the username and password is correct.

I believe the problem is with the `window.location.href` method. I want to navigate to a local page, not an online one.

Van anyone suggest another way to do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            if (typeof(localStorage) === 'undefined' ) {
                alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.');
            } else {
                        $("#return_form2").submit(function(){//load the items
                getItems(); 

                });
            }
        });

    var getItems = function() {

                    var timeLog, logLength, i;              
            i = 0;
            logLength = localStorage.length-1; //how many items are in the database starting with zero
                    timeLog = '';

            // loop through each item in the database
            for (i = 0; i <= logLength; i++) {
                            var itemKey, value, values, firstname, password, email;
                //variables for the key and values
                itemKey = localStorage.key(i);

                value = localStorage.getItem(itemKey);
                            values = JSON.parse(value);
                firstname = values.fname;
                password = values.pass;
                email = values.email;
                course = values.class;






    var tt = course;
    var un = document.return_form2.username.value;
    var pw = document.return_form2.password.value;
    var web = "Web Systems Development";


    if ((un == firstname) && (pw == password) && (tt == web)){
    window.location.href = "AppMenu.html";
    return false;
    }
    else {
    alert ("Incorrect Password");
    }
    }}
```

Comment: If `tt == web`? does `web` equal `course`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that `((un == firstname) && (pw == password) && (tt == web))` is `true`, anyway,  the next line worked for me

```
window.location="AppMenu.html";
```

Also you don't have to return `false`